# appium: Activity doesn't exist or cannot be launched when try to open MyFiles with android 10

Tags: appium, adb, android-10.0

So I have `S20` connected to my machine, this devices can be seen using `adb devices` command.

OS is `Android 10` and I try to open `MyFiles` using this `credentials`:

```
{
  "appPackage": "com.sec.android.app.myfiles",
  "automationName": "uiautomator2",
  "deviceName": "S20",
  "newCommandTimeout": 1500,
  "noReset": true,
  "resetKeyboard": true,
  "udid": "RFEN2994EEF",
  "unicodeKeyboard": true,
  "platformName": "Android",
  "appActivity": ".common.MainActivity"
}
```

And got this `error`:

> An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
> Original error: Cannot start the 'com.sec.android.app.myfiles'
> application. Original error: Activity name '.common.MainActivity' used
> to start the app doesn't exist or cannot be launched! Make sure it
> exists and is a launchable activity

So I try to open manually `MyFiles` and run this `command`:

```
adb shell "dumpsys window windows | grep -E 'mCurrentFocus|mFocusedApp'"
```

But no output received.

**Update**

```
<activity
            android:theme="@ref/0x7f0f0128"
            android:name="com.sec.android.app.myfiles.external.ui.MainActivity"
            android:taskAffinity="@string/0x24"
            android:launchMode="2"
            android:configChanges="0x1ff7"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="0x20">

<activity
            android:theme="@ref/0x7f0f0129"
            android:name="com.sec.android.app.myfiles.external.ui.MultiInstanceLaunchActivity"
            android:taskAffinity="@string/0x24">

<activity
            android:theme="@ref/0x7f0f0128"
            android:name="com.sec.android.app.myfiles.external.ui.activity.MainActivity1"
            android:taskAffinity="@string/0x24"
            android:launchMode="2"
            android:configChanges="0x1ff7">

<activity
            android:theme="@ref/0x7f0f0128"
            android:name="com.sec.android.app.myfiles.external.ui.activity.MainActivity2"
            android:taskAffinity="@string/0x24"
            android:launchMode="2"
            android:configChanges="0x1ff7">

<activity
            android:theme="@ref/0x7f0f0128"
            android:name="com.sec.android.app.myfiles.external.ui.activity.MainActivity3"
            android:taskAffinity="@string/0x24"
            android:launchMode="2"
            android:configChanges="0x1ff7">

<activity
            android:theme="@ref/0x7f0f0128"
            android:name="com.sec.android.app.myfiles.external.ui.activity.MainActivity4"
            android:taskAffinity="@string/0x24"
            android:launchMode="2"
            android:configChanges="0x1ff7">

<activity
            android:theme="@ref/0x7f0f012b"
            android:name="com.sec.android.app.myfiles.external.ui.SettingsActivity"
            android:exported="false"
            android:configChanges="0x1f80">

<activity
            android:theme="@ref/0x7f0f0127"
            android:name="com.sec.android.app.myfiles.external.ui.BottomSheetActivity"
            android:configChanges="0x480" />

        <activity
            android:theme="@ref/0x7f0f0128"
            android:label="SamsungDriveAccountActivity"
            android:name="com.sec.android.app.myfiles.external.account.SamsungDriveLoginActivity"
            android:exported="false"
            android:configChanges="0x1ff7">

<activity
            android:theme="@ref/0x7f0f0128"
            android:label="GoogleDriveLoginActivity"
            android:name="com.sec.android.app.myfiles.external.account.GoogleDriveLoginActivity"
            android:exported="false"
            android:configChanges="0x1ff7">

<activity
            android:theme="@ref/0x7f0f0128"
            android:label="OneDriveLoginActivity"
            android:name="com.sec.android.app.myfiles.external.account.OneDriveLoginActivity"
            android:exported="false"
            android:configChanges="0x1ff7">

<activity
            android:theme="@ref/0x7f0f019c"
            android:label="@ref/0x7f0a003b"
            android:name="com.sec.android.app.myfiles.external.ui.BixbyActivity"
            android:exported="false"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:configChanges="0x1ff7">

<activity
            android:theme="@ref/0x7f0f012c"
            android:label="@ref/0x7f0a003b"
            android:name="com.sec.android.app.myfiles.external.ui.PickerActivity"
            android:launchMode="1"
            android:configChanges="0x1ff7">

<activity
            android:name="com.microsoft.identity.client.AuthenticationActivity"
            android:configChanges="0x4a0" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.microsoft.identity.client.BrowserTabActivity"
            android:exported="true" />

        <activity
            android:theme="@ref/0x01030010"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInHubActivity"
            android:exported="false"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true" />

<activity
            android:theme="@ref/0x01030010"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiActivity"
            android:exported="false" />
```

Comment: When I look into the apk I downloaed from ApkPure.com then I don't see `.common.MainActivity`. I only have an `.external.ui.MainActivity`. If you get an error that an activity does not exist check the APK and it's `AndroidManifest.xml` if the activity you want to start really exists.

Comment: So you suggest to replace .common.MainActivity with .external.ui.MainActivity ?

Comment: I suggest to extract the APK, decode it's AndroidManifest.xml and find out the correct activity class name.

Comment: How can I do this ?

Comment: Get the APK, decode `AndroidManifest.xml` and check the `<activity` entries that are exported. All these steps has been asked multiple times here on SO.

Comment: Please see my update

Comment: Then you now have the MainActivity class name you can use.